# Unable to move directory in azure using ShareDirectoryClient

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Normally we can move the directory using

```
    // source is: "C:\Songs\Elvis my Man"
    // newLocation is: "C:\Songs\Elvis"
    
    try
    {
        // Previous command was: Directory.Move(source, newLocation);
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(source);
        dir.MoveTo(newLocation);
    }

catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: "+ e.Message);
}
```

Now, when using the azure:

```
        string myconnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        string myshareName = "Mysampleshare";
        string mydirName = "Mysampledir";            
        // Get a reference to a share and then create it
        ShareClient myshare = new ShareClient(myconnectionString, myshareName);           
        ShareDirectoryClient directory1 = myshare.GetDirectoryClient(mydirName);

       
        string myshareName2 = "Mysampleshare2";
        string mydirName2 = "Mysampledir2";            
        // Get a reference to a share and then create it
        ShareClient myshare2 = new ShareClient(myconnectionString, myshareName2);           
        ShareDirectoryClient directory2 = myshare2.GetDirectoryClient(mydirName2);
        Directory.Move(directory1.Path, directory2.Path);
```

I am unable to move the directory from one location to another using azure. I am getting exception.

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: The path specified by sourceDirName is invalid
```

Please suggest your advice.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exception you’re getting.

Answer (score 3):

`ShareDirectoryClient` essentially implements Azure File Service REST API thus you cannot use `System.IO` operations like `Directory.Move` with it.

There are two possible solutions:

1. If you want to use the SDK, what you will need to do is list files and directories recursively in the source directory and then copy individual files from source directory to target directory. You will also need to create directories in the target directory as well. Once the copy operation is complete, then you will need to delete all files and directories from the source directory. Once the source directory is empty, only then you will be able to delete the source directory.

You will need to do all this because the REST API does not natively support move operation. To accomplish move, you will need to perform copy operation followed by delete operation.

2. If you want to use `System.IO`, then you will need to mount the file share as a shared network drive so that you can get a drive letter assigned to that file share. Once you have that, then you will be able to use operations like `Directory.Move` available in System.IO namespace.

**UPDATE**

Please try the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;

namespace SO69798149
{
    class Program
    {
        const string MyconnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
        const string MyshareName = "share-name";
        const string SourceDirectoryName = "source-directory-name";
        private const string RenamedDirectoryName = "new-directory-name";
        
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShareClient myshare = new ShareClient(MyconnectionString, MyshareName);
            ShareDirectoryClient sourceDirectoryClient = myshare.GetDirectoryClient(SourceDirectoryName);
            ShareDirectoryClient targetDirectoryClient = myshare.GetDirectoryClient(RenamedDirectoryName);
            await RenameDirectory(sourceDirectoryClient, targetDirectoryClient);
            Console.WriteLine("Directory renamed.");
        }

        static async Task RenameDirectory(ShareDirectoryClient sourceDirectoryClient,
            ShareDirectoryClient targetDirectoryClient)
        {
            //Create target directory
            await targetDirectoryClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            //List files and folders from the source directory
            var result = sourceDirectoryClient.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync();
            await foreach (var items in result.AsPages())
            {
                foreach (var item in items.Values)
                {
                    if (item.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        //If item is directory, then get the child items in that directory recursively.
                        await RenameDirectory(sourceDirectoryClient.GetSubdirectoryClient(item.Name),
                            targetDirectoryClient.GetSubdirectoryClient(item.Name));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If item is file, then copy the file and then delete it.
                        var sourceFileClient = sourceDirectoryClient.GetFileClient(item.Name);
                        var targetFileClient = targetDirectoryClient.GetFileClient(item.Name);
                        await targetFileClient.StartCopyAsync(sourceFileClient.Uri);
                        await sourceFileClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            //Delete source directory.
            await sourceDirectoryClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do u have any reference code. Thanks!

Comment: Right now I don't, sorry. Let me try to write some sample code and share (don't hold your breath though :)).

Comment: Updated my answer with code. HTH.